# php zval different in Object type

Tags: php, object, reference

when I am study the PHP  Reference Counting Basics.I can not understand the refcount in the object type; I use the php5.6 with Xdebug v2.2.5 on the windows to test

```
  class  A{
   private $a1;
   public $a2;

  }
$class = new A();
xdebug_debug_zval('class');
```

when I use the xdebug to test  this is the output result.

```
class:
(refcount=1, is_ref=0),
object(A)[1]
  private 'a1' => (refcount=2, is_ref=0),null
  public 'a2' => (refcount=2, is_ref=0),null
```

I can not understand why the refcount in object member values is 2